# Is there a version of Audacity that will run on Alpine Linux?

Tags: audacity, alpine-linux

I was trying to get the Gentoo version from the Audacity website, but as far as I can tell, Audacity is not ready for Gentoo Linux yet.

Anyone know if the Ubuntu version will work on Alpine? Or one of the others?

Answer (score 1):

Alpine is based on musl libc, there **will** be issues when trying to run most graphical binary programs that are were compiled and linked with glibc toolchain.

Meanwhile Alpine at least had a recipe for building Audacity from source. Why you do not follow it? http://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/tree/main/audacity/APKBUILD?id=567085595974ab0c33551dc4e138f747829b968f

Answer (score 1):

Audacity is in Alpine community repository.
You can install it with:

```
 apk add audacity
```

If there are specific feature you want to be enabled, feel free to create a feature request in the [Alpine Bugtracker](https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/projects/alpine)

Answer (score -1):

Remember to enable the community repository by editing `/etc/apk/repositories` and then use:

```
apk update
apk add audacity
```

At a minimum you need to get ALSA enabled, otherwise all inputs and outputs in audacity will show as blank. Follow these instructions:

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Sound_Setup